# DataTables select row update date in database

Tags: jquery, coldfusion

How do you use the select method in jquerys DataTables to update the database? What I am trying to figure out is how to select a row on the DataTable and for it to update a couple fields in the database by clicking a button. When the button is clicked I would like it to submit todays date in the Date_Complete section in the database. How to you update rows like this?

```
var table = $('#processing').DataTable();
$('#processing tbody').on( 'click', 'tr', function () {
    var rowdata = table.row( this ).data();
console.log(rowdata);
} );
```

[image]
rowdata.id = 5

I am able to get the array in JS but how can I convert this to grab the id of the correct row and then update the Date_Complete for that row in ColdFusion?

```
    <cffunction name="updateRecord" access="remote" returntype="void">
    <cfargument name="id" type="numeric" required="true">
     <cfset var completeBatch = ''> 
    <cfquery name="completeBatch">
        UPDATE dbo.Dealer_Track_Work 
        SET    Date_Complete = getDate()
        WHERE  ID = <cfqueryparam value="#arguments.id#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer">
    </cfquery>
</cffunction>
```

How do I pass the ID from the JS to the CF Function?

**Updated JS** but AJAX still is not running updateRecord:
Receiving "Invalid CFML construct found on line 1 at column 1." for my function.

```
    $(document).ready(function () {

        var table = $('#processing').DataTable();

        // Decide if row from datatable is chosen or not to display Modal
        $('#CompleteIt').click(function(){
            var rowIndex = $('#selectedRow').val();

            if (rowIndex){
                console.log("Item ID: " + rowIndex);
            } else {
                console.log("No item id selected!");
                alert("Please select batch to be completed.");
                return false;
            }
        });

        // When row is selected from datatable assign item id to hidden "selectedRow" textbox
        $('#processing tbody').on( 'click', 'tr', function () {
            var rowdata = table.row( this ).data();
            console.log(rowdata);
            var selectedIndex = $('#selectedRow').val();

            if (selectedIndex == rowdata.id) {
                $('#selectedRow').val('');
            }
            else {
                $('#selectedRow').val(rowdata.id);
            }
        });

        // What happens when a user hits the "Accept" button on the dealer form
        $(".completed_accept").click(function(){
            var CompletedName = $("#CompletedName").val();
            if (!CompletedName){ 
                alert("Please select associate.");
                if ($.browser.Chrome) {
                    $('#CompletedName').click();
                } else {
                    $('#CompletedName').focus();
                }
                return false;
            } else {
                $('#AssociateCompleted').modal('hide');
            }
        });

        $('#employeeLoggedOut').on('submit', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        //alert($(this).serialize());
        $.ajax({
            // the location of the CFC to run
            url: "proxy/Completed.cfm",
            // send a GET HTTP operation
            type: "post",
            // tell jQuery we're getting JSON back
            dataType: "json",
            // send the data to the CFC
             data: $('#selectedRow').serialize(),
            // this gets the data returned on success
            success: function (data) {
                console.log(data);
                window.location.reload();
            }, 
            // this runs if an error
            error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                // show error
                console.log(errorThrown);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

How do I invoke the function to run the method and pass the ID to the argument?

How do I get my JS rowdata.id to be what equals `WHERE id =` in the CF function?

`WHERE  id = <cfqueryparam value="#arguments.id#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer">`

Comment: You need to modify your CFC function to accept a single argument: the "id".  Then use `arguments.id` in your query.  Inside your JS on click function, invoke the cfc with [`ajax()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)  and pass in the extracted the "id" value.

Comment: Start with [something like this](http://trycf.com/gist/26e37d5869d993000788/acf11?theme=monokai). I will leave you to figure out the `ajax()` call on your own.  Do a search. Plenty of examples on S.O.  I assume the query is psuedo SQL as there is no UPDATE INTO command AFAIK.  BTW, did you ask something similar recently? The structure seems very familiar ...

Comment: I meant localize the query name, so it is only accessible within the function. This avoids potential threading problems. In CF8 you can only do this by pre-declaring the variables with the VAR keyword *before* they are used ie `<cfset var completeBatch = "">`. CF9 supports a simpler syntax. No need to pre-declare variables, simply append the LOCAL scope when they are used, such as in the cfquery tag   ie  `<cfquery name="LOCAL.completeBatch" ...>`.

Comment: Updated my response regarding the ajax call

Comment: *Receiving "Invalid CFML construct found on line 1 at column 1." for my function.*  You are trying to do too much at once.  There is no point calling the CF code from javascript if it does not even compile. Verify the `.cfc` compiles AND that it works from CF first. *After* it does, then try calling it from javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Original

A JQuery `DataTable` is used to work with HTML *tables* in a client-side web page, not to work with data*bases* (e.g. MySQL, PostgreSQL, etc), which tend to be server-side.

From their [description](https://www.datatables.net/) --my emphasis--:

> DataTables is a plug-in for the jQuery Javascript library. It is a
>   highly flexible tool, based upon the foundations of progressive
>   enhancement, and will add advanced interaction controls to any **HTML
>   table**.

#### EDIT 1

> For some reason my:
>   `$.get('dealerTracking.cfc?method=updateRecord&id=rowdata.id');`
>   is not firing and it is skipping this step.

I think the reason for your call getting "skipped" here is that you're supposed to include the host name of the server you want to contact, but you didn't so it only gives the *appearance* of it being skipped. Whenever I've done AJAX calls, they tend to follow this pattern:

```
$.get('https://hostname.domain/server-side-script-to-contact ...')
```

But your code is missing the host name information and it seems it wouldn't know *who* to contact.

Also, your `var CompletedName = $("#CompletedName").val();` is potentially suspect, especially since you use this within the `else` block and it might be getting skipped entirely if it enters the `if`'s body instead --which is determined by whatever input you happen to have, so I can't tell here.

#### EDIT 2

> all i am trying to do is when the button is clicked use js to call the cf function to update the row of the date saying that its now completed

Here's a small portion of an example using AJAX (don't have a server to test right now, but the layout should put you in the right direction). In this case, the JS code uses AJAX to send a request to a server page, with some arguments for the script that the server will call.

```
[...]
<body>
    <button id="AjaxRequestButton" onclick="sendAjaxRequest();">Send AJAX Request</button>
    <br/><br/>
    <input id="ServerResponseBox" type="text" style="width: 50%;" readonly></button>
</body>

<script>
// sends HTTP request in the background when button is pressed
function sendAjaxRequest() {
    console.log("Sending AJAX request to server...");
    $.ajax({
        type    : "GET",                // type of request: GET HTTP request
        url     : "ajax_demo.pl",       // script to execute in our case
        data    : "action=add_msg&msg='my-message'", // arguments for server script; can be user inputs retrieved from widgets, etc.

        // anonymous function callback invoked when server response arrives
        success : function(json_data) {
            // process server response
            console.log("Received server response.");
            $("[id='ServerResponseBox']").val(json_data.message);   // notice we never refreshed entire page for this
            // alert("Server response is: " + json_data.message);
        },
        dataType: "json"    // client-side should expect JSON-type data for the callback above
    });
}
</script>
[...]
```

This page has a button and makes sure its `onclick` event is set to invoke the JS function `sendAjaxRequest`, which is defined later. The function has the `$.ajax({ ... })` call (JQuery offers several ways to do this), which sends the arguments as part of the request. This is done specifically by these two lines:

```
url     : "ajax_demo.pl",
data    : "action=add_msg&msg='my-message'"
```

The `url` is what you need to call on the server (i.e. the page/script), the `data` is where you pass in arguments for your script to use and determine what to do.

A skeleton program for the server (sorry, Perl is what I have right now, but it's pretty straightforward) would look similar to something like this, where you'd get the contents sent in by the client AJAX call, do something of interest, and then return some kind of response.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

# CPAN modules
use CGI;
use JSON;

print "Content-type: text/html\n\n";

my %args = # parse request URL here to get arguments

if( defined( $args{action} ) ){
    if($args{action} eq "add_msg") {
        print add_message( $args{msg} );
    }
} else {
    print default_response();
}

sub add_message {
    # create database connection,
    # execute SQL query against database
    # return a message to let the client know how things went
    my $json = { message => "some message for client" };
    return encode_json($json);
}

sub default_response {
    my $json = { message => "The meaning of life is... 42? o.O" };
    return encode_json($json);
}
```

I hope this puts you in the right path.

Comment: True, but you can easily make an ajax call *to* a server-side script when the "click" event is triggered.

Comment: @Leigh: True, but the OP's original wording did not seem to suggest he was referring to that. The original question has been improved in the last 12+ hours, though.

Comment: @DavidBrierton - Did you delete *all* of your comments or was that a moderator?